# RuntimeError: derivative for aten::floor_divide is not implemented with loss.backward()

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error, backpropagation, loss

I am implementing the Charbonnier loss as follows:

```
class loss_function(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, epsilon=1e-3):
    super(loss_function,self).__init__()
    self.epsilon = epsilon

  def forward(self,pred,truth):
    return torch.mean(torch.sqrt((pred-truth)**2 + self.epsilon**2))
```

But there is a problem during the training phase. When the algorithm reaches the backpropagation steps `loss.backward()` this error occours:

`RuntimeError: derivative for aten::floor_divide is not implemented`

I am sure about the format of the tensor that I pass to the loss function.

I tried to search about the problem, but the results are vague and not specific.